# SHA-512 checksum

Tags: c#, testing, sha512

There has been made an copy program in C# and in that application checksum SHA-512 has been used to verify that input and output of the copy process is/are identical, I need to test and verify the checksum functionality but find it hard to test. I need to see whether the algorithm works as intended use. Are there any of you who have good ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Any reason you don't just use the built-in `SHA512` class? That's been unit tested for you when the framework was built. (And if you *are* using that, what's your question?)

Comment: You're asking whether or not you're creating the checksum correctly? Post your code so people can see.

Comment: try to formulate a good question - we can't see what's on your screen or in your head. For example: put sample code and tell us where its behaviour differs from your expectations.    I look at your question and I have no clue why SHA512 is mentioned (any other checksum would have been the same) or if you're testing the "copy program" or the checksum implementation itself

Comment: Hi guys, thanx for your response, the program works fine but actually I need to test the whole program and especially test or verify the checksum. how can I, give the program an input e.g. a file and in the process modify the file somehow in order to see that checksum get that error ? thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @eat_code_repeat What do you find hard? Take some input; hash it; modify the input; hash it again; check that first hash is not equal to second hash.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to verify that your output is correct, you could compare your output to the output of existing services.

A quick search came up with a few:

https://md5file.com/calculator

https://defuse.ca/checksums.htm